# Calculating a total cost from JComboBox with ItemEvent

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have two `JComboBox` components and a `JLabel`. The two combo boxes both contain Strings and the label is supposed to have the price added. My issue is that I can not figure out how to set int values to the combo box selections and then add those integerss and make them output on the label. So far it sticks at 0 and doesn't change.

All code corrections/constructive criticism welcome.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CottageRental extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    // Declare all instance data  (primitives and objects used) 
    private int WIDTH = 675;
    private int HEIGHT = 320; 
    Container con; 
    JButton [] button; 
    JLabel label1, label2, label3;
    JComboBox box1, box2;
    String[] box1options = {"1 Bedroom - $600", "2 Bedroom - $800", "3 Bedrooms - $1,000"};
    String[] box2options = {"Horse Back Riding - $60", "Rafting - $40", "Row  Boat Rental - $50"};
    int[] box1prices = {600, 800, 1000};
    int[] box2prices = {60, 40, 50};
    private Font font1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
    public int total1, total2;
    //constructor 
    public CottageRental() {
        super("Cottage Rental"); 
        con = getContentPane(); 
        con.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        con.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

        //instantiate all the components in the constructor 

    }

    public void createGUI() {
        label1 = new JLabel("WoodBerry Cottage Rental");
        label1.setFont(font1);
        label1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label2 = new JLabel("Rental Amount Due: " + total1 + " and " + total2);
        box1 = new JComboBox(box1options);
        box2 = new JComboBox(box2options);
        con.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        con.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        con.add(box1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        con.add(box2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        box1.addItemListener(this);
        box2.addItemListener(this);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CottageRental   object  = new CottageRental(); 
        object.createGUI(); 
    }


    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {  
            if (source == box1) {
                int choice1 = box1.getSelectedIndex();
                if (choice1 == 0) {
                    total1 = box1prices[0];
                } else if (choice1 == 1) {
                    total1 = box1prices[1];
                } else if (choice1 == 2) {
                    total1 = box1prices[2];
                }
            }
            if (source == box2) {
                int choice2 = box2.getSelectedIndex();
                if (choice2 == 0) {
                    total2 = box2prices[0];
                } else if (choice2 == 1) {
                    total2 = box2prices[1];
                } else if (choice2 == 2) {
                    total2 = box2prices[2];
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could condense your `public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)` method because you already know the selected index is the same as the index in your price arrays. You already assigned int values indirectly by having those price arrays that match the size of the JComboBox. Also, the label wouldn't change because you don't update the text on your label.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        if(source.equals(box1) || source.equals(box2) {
            total1 = box1prices[box1.getSelectedIndex()];
            total2 = box2prices[box2.getSelectedIndex()];
            label2.setText("Rental Amount Due: " + total1 + " and " + total2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't think of this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Start by making a POJO (Plain Old Java Object), which carries the description AND the price separately.

```
public class Product {
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product(String description, double price) {
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getDescription() + " - " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(getPrice());
    }
}
```

Now, use this to build your options...

```
private Product[] box1options = {
    new Product("1 Bedroom", 600), 
    new Product("2 Bedroom", 800),
    new Product("3 Bedroomsm", 1_000)};
private Product[] box2options = {
    new Product("Horse Back Riding", 60), 
    new Product("Rafting", 40), 
    new Product("Row  Boat Rental", 50)};
private JComboBox<Product> box1Prices = new JComboBox<Product>(box1options);
private JComboBox<Product> box2Prices = new JComboBox<Product>(box2options);
```

Then update your listeners...

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        updateTally();
    }
};

box1Prices.addActionListener(listener);
box2Prices.addActionListener(listener);
```

And finally update the logic for the tally...

```
protected void updateTally() {
    Product p1 = (Product) box1Prices.getSelectedItem();
    Product p2 = (Product) box2Prices.getSelectedItem();

    double price1 = p1 != null ? p1.getPrice() : 0d;
    double price2 = p2 != null ? p2.getPrice() : 0d;

    tallyLabel.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price1 + price2));
}
```

This way, you encompass the price with the description in a single unit of work, making it easier to change the price (or description) without having to change the rest of the code